# Deploy to AWS CodeDeploy using Bitbucket Pipes

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm using `AWS CodeDeploy app on Bitbucket` and now Bitbucket announced `End of support 2019-12-03`

I'm getting this message every time when I deploy.

> Deprecation Notice
>
> Bitbucket is removing this app on 1 Jun 2020. You can use the `AWS CodeDeploy pipe` instead.
>   Read more about this change.

But I cannot find a migration guide to start using `AWS CodeDeploy pipe`.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Deploy to AWS with CodeDeploy](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-to-aws-with-codedeploy-976773337.html) deployment guide from Bitbucket. You should be able to use this guide to start deploying your code using CodeDeploy.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen it, it is really aweful. The CodePloy pipe example repository is not working. First - it does not zip the file, it does not pic up the s3 bucket name, the Pipe version is outdated and so on and so forth.